# Reactjs - Multiple choice questions - store state as array

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactjs form where the values are stored in state as follows

```
<input className="form-control" type="{inputType}" defaultValue="" name={this.props.questionInfo.module_question_id} key={this.props.questionInfo.module_question_id} onBlur={(e) => this.props.handleChange(e, inputType)} />
```

handleChange method is as follows

```
handleChange = (e, type) => {
    let formValues = this.state.formValues;
    let value = this.fetchValue(e, type)
    formValues[e.target.name] = value;
    this.setState({formValues: formValues});
    console.log(this.state.formValues);
  }
```

Now i have a question that can have multiple answers. User can select multiple checkboxes as answer.

The format should be

```
formValues: {
   questionid_1: ans1_id,
   questionid_2: ans2_id,
   .
   .
   questionid_5: [answer1_id, answer2_id....]  
}
```

The problem is that the handlechange method is looking only the current element. In this case multiple elements are to be chekced and corresponding array needs to be generated.

How to modifiy the current method? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider **storing all the option answers as array format**, therefore for single choice answers, array will have only one element, for multiple answers, array will have multiple options. You also might have to categorize questions accordingly and put relevant checks in-place.

Updated code can look something like this.

```
handleChange = (e, type) => {
    let formValues = this.state.formValues;
    let value = this.fetchValue(e, type);
    formValues[e.target.name] = formValues[e.target.name] || [];
    formValues[e.target.name] = [...formValues[e.target.name], value];
    this.setState({formValues: formValues});
    console.log(this.state.formValues);
  }
```

Here we are making sure formValues[e.target.name] is valid array.
Then we append the latest value to this array.
Thus all the answers now will be of type array, providing consistency across question answers. Avoiding complexity.

Hope this helps, thanks.